# How to plot a histogram of pixel values of a text present in an image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, histogram

I have text identified using rnn and these inside bounding box i would like to plot a histogram of their pixel values.[image]

Comment: please show your own effort into answering your question.

Comment: i am not sure how to approach this.. i was not looking for exact code, but a way to approach

Comment: did you look on the internet before asking? what did you find?

Comment: you can post this as a solution and i can upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, one easy way is the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image  # I assume the image is loaded as a numpy array

plt.hist(image.flatten())
plt.show()
```